# Cannot import package in server worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Every time I import a package in background.js, the extension will shows "service worker(inactive)".

This is my background:

```
//import {INavigationLogEntry} from "../interfaces";
//import {COMMANDS} from "../ultrasonic/CONSTS";
 //import {simplePrepend} from "../utils/shared-utils";

//
//COMMANDS = require("../ultrasonic/CONSTS");
//script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("../ultrasonic/CONSTS");

chrome.alarms.create({ periodInMinutes: 1 });
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage());
//
 chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(async(details)=>{
//     await  simplePrepend(COMMANDS.NAVGATION,{
//         url:details.url
//     });
   console.log("Recorded navigation:"+details.url);
 });
```

this is my manifest.json(partial):

```
 "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "src/background/background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
```

I tried use require, but still get the same error.

Comment: Assuming you don't use webpack/rollup, there's a mistake in your code: the ES module `import` must include the extension e.g. `interfaces.js`. If there's still an error after fixing all names, keep the imports commented out, reload the extension, open devtools by clicking service worker in chrome://extensions, then run `import("../interfaces.js")` in console and do the same for every module.